# JQuery Shake Breaking Script & Vertical Align Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Looking at [JQuery Shake Effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/) to shake my file input field upon an invalid file format or size being attempted to upload, all I need to add is the following;

```
$( "#toggle" ).effect( "shake" );
```

However upon implementing this to my script it breaks everything afterwards;

```
if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(uploadFile.name)) {

    $('#file').effect( "shake" );

    $('#file').text('You must select an image file only');
    setTimeout(function() { $('#file').text('Choose file');},5000);
    goUpload = false;
}
```

I am also having the problem centering my text even though I've set the vertical-align.

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/t5euj5j4/

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/t5euj5j4/1/ *-Forgot to add JQuery UI!*

Comment: you need to include jquery-ui.js

Comment: BANG! When it smacks you in the face, programming too long! Well that's half the question, thanks @AbrahamUribe +1

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

**Problem One:**

@AbrahamUribe pointed out I had stupidly not linked to the JQueryUI.

**Problem Two**

Instead of...

```
vertical-align: 35px;
```

...being used, the following should be used to align text to the center;

```
line-height: 35px;
```